# Is Thread.Abort() ever called by the .NET runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

I've inherited some service code and I'm trying to track down an issue with service crashes. I've found the following code in many places:

```
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
    throw;
}
```

However, I can't find any calls to `Thread.Abort()` or `Thread.Kill()` in any parts of the project (or related projects).

Is `Thread.Abort()` ever implicitly called by the .NET runtime, or does that exception exist only to catch calls that a developer makes? I'm trying to narrow my error avenues and I'm not very experienced with threads in C#. I'm trying to determine whether the catch block I've shown is ever actually hit if `Thread.Abort()` is never actually called in my codebase.

Thanks!

Edit: I want to clarify - I know that .NET can kill threads, but I was wondering if it specifically calls `Thread.Abort()` or whether it uses some other means (as the `ThreadAbortException` is only called on `Thread.Abort()`.

Comment: Yes, the runtime aborts threads.  These are *rude* aborts, triggered on AppDomain unloads, they don't trigger that code.  Avoid assuming that the previous programmer knew what he was doing or properly sanitized his code.  He perhaps figured out it wasn't such a great idea after all.  It wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch/throw without doing anything about it seems pointless.

These errors are common in ASP.NET-- it means a redirect that ended the response, eg. [ASP.NET Response.Redirect( ) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220875/asp-net-response-redirect-error/6220897#6220897)

or it means a worker process was killed by casinni/iis/aspnet for it's own mysterious reasons, maybe worker process recycles, etc.

It normally doesn't indicate a programming error.

Calling Thread.Abort() in multi-threaded apps appears to be a bad idea in most cases and other answers on SO speak to that better than I could.

Comment: If the thread was aborted and that exception is thrown.....the exception will bubble through the call stack, right? Do exceptions bubble across threads - would it propagate to the parent thread?

Comment: Rarely I've seen these make it into error logs (collected in the error handler on global asax) and on development machines where are often doing unusual things like killing the casinni process, or killing iis, or other rough shut downs.

Comment: Ah interesting: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/threadabortexception.cs#1b47a5a85e0d5883 ThreadAbortException means a thread died/was killed on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I want to clarify - I know that .NET can kill threads, but I was
>   wondering if it specifically calls Thread.Abort() or whether it uses
>   some other means (as the ThreadAbortException is only called on
>   Thread.Abort().

If you're really interested to see whether (and where) it does that, refer to [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), it's pretty complete. Specifically, it shows that `Thread.Abort` is referenced at [these places](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs#fbdd377484783e1b#references).